# Как удобно работать с gulp при вёрстке?

Tags: вёрстка, gulp, npm

День добрый.

Недавно начал использовать gulp для вёрстки макетов. Сверстав несколько проектов, у меня набрался некий набор пакетов, которые требовались везде и будут продолжаться требоваться. И вот каждый новый проект начинается с перекачивания всех нужных пакетов, включая зависимости в папку нового проекта, а это уже 60mb.

Собственно вопрос, можно ли как-то сделать доступными все нужные пакеты в рамках одной машины, чтобы в папке проекта был только gulpfile? Или я что-то делаю не так?

Comment: разделите их в devDependencies, по идее тогда они должны ставиться на машине (если версии не различаются). Но вообще не очень понятна проблема, ну весят они 60 мб, это много или что?

Comment: @Artem Gorlachev проблема в дублировании файлов. Думал, может, есть способ создать единожды пространство в компьютере, в котором в новых проектах изначально доступен весь привычный инструментарий.

Comment: Лучше всего глобально ничего не ставить, так как зависимости и версии от проекта к проекту могут отличаться. При возникновении конфликтов боль будет больше, чем от 60-ти мб.